# KnockoutJS Get the Text and Value of Select

Tags: knockout.js

I have this line of code for the select:

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.Countries, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value',  value: $root.SelectedDialogCountry, optionsCaption: 'All'"></select>
```

I can get the value selected with "Value" but I would also like to get the "Text"

> example:  **Text:** United States of America  **Value:** USA

Is there a way for me to get the "United States of America"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the `optionsValue: 'Value'` attribute from the binding. This will set the entire *Country* object as the value in `SelectedDialogCountry` observable. ([Documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#example-3-drop-down-list-representing-arbitrary-javascript-objects-not-just-strings))

Here's a working snippet.

```js
function viewModel() {
  const self = this;
  self.Countries = ko.observableArray([
    { Text: "United States of America", Value: "USA" },
    { Text: "China", Value: "CHN" },
    { Text: "India", Value: "IND" }]);
    
  self.SelectedDialogCountry = ko.observable();
  
  self.SelectedDialogCountry.subscribe(_ => {
    console.log(self.SelectedDialogCountry().Text)
    console.log(self.SelectedDialogCountry().Value)
  })
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: Countries,
                       optionsText: 'Text',
                       value: SelectedDialogCountry,
                       optionsCaption: 'Select'"></select>
```